# Why does string::find_first_of() return unexpected result?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, c++11, while-loop

My code is following:

```
string s_1 = "ssissippi";
string s = "si";
size_t pos = s_1.find_first_of(s);
while (pos != string::npos)
{
    cout << pos << endl;
    pos++;
    pos = s_1.find_first_of(s, pos);
}
```

And I get such result:
0,1,2,3,4,5,8.
I can not figure out what leads to the answer. 
I will really appreciate for any help.

Comment: What result did you expect?

Comment: Also, from [this `std::string::find_first_of` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of): "Finds the first character equal to ***one*** of the characters in the given character sequence."

Comment: I believe you're not alone who misread doc. So the question may be useful for others.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I misunderstand the function of "string::find_first_of". Really sorry for that, my poor English.

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov Thank you. My poor English makes me not understand the reference well. Really shamed!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you mean member function `find()` instead of `find_first_of()`

For example:

```
string s_1 = "ssissippi";
string s = "si";
size_t pos = s_1.find(s);
while (pos != string::npos)
{
    cout << pos << endl;
    pos++;
    pos = s_1.find(s, pos);
}
```

The member function `find_first_of()` finds the first position in the source string where one of the characters stores in the string specified as the argument is present.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have known where I am wrong at by read again the reference.

Answer (score 7):

Your `find_first_of`does :

> Finds the first character equal to one of the characters in str.

So it doesn't check for the string *"si"* being there (like you probably expected) but rather either 's' or 'i'. Use `std::string::find()` to check for the whole string.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've gotten that. Thanks for your aid.